# How to avoid gray outline artefacts when converting an eps image to pdf?

Tags: pdf, gnuplot, file-conversion, eps

To generate vector graphics figures with LaTeX labels, I use gnuplot and the cairolatex terminal, creating the image via `plot "data.txt" u 1:2:3 matrix with image notitle` followed by:

```
latex figuregen.tex
dvips -E -ofile.eps figuregen

# Correct the bounding box automatically:
epstool --copy --bbox file.eps filename.eps

## Create a pdf:
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dEPSCrop filename.eps filename.pdf
```

Here is a zoom on a specific region of the original eps image:
[image: eps file]
White regions actually correspond to NaN values in the data file.

Now using the pdf file converted from eps:
[image: after conversion to pdf]
**In the pdf version, there are now unwanted outlines around all the NaN pixels, creating an awful lot of noise in the higher portion of the image**.

**I want to have these images as pdf, free of artefacts, and preserve high-quality LaTeX labels.** I suspect that there might be a `ps2pdf` option to deactivate this kind of unwanted behaviour but I just cannot find it.

I tried things such as: `-dGraphicsAlphaBits=1`, `-dNOINTERPOLATE`, `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`, `-dNOTRANSPARENCY`, `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4` or `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5`, but without success.

I also tried fixing this directly in `gnuplot`, but without success (see e.g. below).

Would any of you know **how to solve this issue?**

**Thank you very much for your time!**

#### EDIT

What's even more surprising and problematic is that these artefacts **also appear when printed**.

Note however that they do not appear at extreme levels of zoom in evince when only a small part of the data set is plotted.

MWE:

```
# plot.plt
set size ratio -1

set palette defined ( 0 '#D73027', 1 '#F46D43', 2 '#FDAE61', 3 '#FEE090', 4 '#FFFFD9', 5 '#E0F3F8', 6 '#ABD9E9', 7 '#74ADD1', 8 '#4575B4' )

#set yr [300:0] ### no artefacts if zoom is higher than 1310% in evince
set yr [400:100] ### no artefacts if zoom is higher than 1780% in evince
#set yr [450:0] ### artefacts at all zoom levels if we show more data, or all of it

set term cairolatex dashed color; set output "temp.tex"

plot "data.txt" u 1:2:3 matrix with image notitle

set output #Closes the temporary output file.   
!sed -e 's|/Title|%/Title|' -e 's|/Subject|%/Subject|' -e 's|/Creator|%/Creator|' -e 's|/Author|%/Author|' < temp.tex > graph.tex
```

and, for completeness:

```
% figuregen.tex

\documentclass[dvips]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} %
\begin{document}
\input graph.tex   
\end{document}
```

If needed, part of the data can be found in text form here; enough to reproduce the issue: https://paste.nomagic.uk/?e0343cc8f759040a#DkRxNiNrH6d3QMZ985CxhA21pG2HpVEShrfjg84uvAdt

#### EDIT 2

In fact, same artefact issues appear when using `set terminal cairolatex pdf`

```
set terminal cairolatex standalone pdf size 16cm,10.5cm dashed transparent
set output "plot.tex"
```

directly with `pdflatex`

```
gnuplot<plot.plt
pdflatex plot.tex
```

(Note, this is using Gnuplot Version 5.2 patchlevel 6).

Comment: Why do you go via latex + dvips? You could use `set terminal cairolatex pdf` and pdflatex. For cropping use pdfcrop

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for your comment but it doesn't seem to help. It leads to similar (and some even worse) artefacts. Though I must say that I have never used the `pdf` option of the `cairolatex` terminal before, so I might have missed something. This first attempt isn't encouraging though.

Comment: @Christoph I've improved my first attempt with `cairolatex pdf` and I am now actually getting the same artefacts. That's very strange. I have also edited my question with more information.

Comment: @Alex just a thought. Is a PNG no option? It seems to be a pixel graphic anyway. I don't see this effect with pngcairo terminal.

Comment: No, this is not an option. While the zoom here only shows pixels, that is only to illustrate the issue. In the actual full image, the LaTeX functionalities are used though. As I said, the objective is to have the final images as pdf, with LaTeX labels as vector. Note that using screenshots and a manual edition in Inkscape to include vector axes and labels by hand for each individual figure wouldn't be considered a viable option either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is, that NaN values are set to transparent black pixels (`#00000000`).

The transparency causes these gray outline artifacts, depending on the zooming level. If you zoom close enough, then you see no artifacts.

But as soon as the image pixels are smaller than your monitor pixels, the values are interpolated for screen display. Its seems that pdf viewers like evince (I tested also okular and mupdf) interpolate both color and alpha channels, so that the alpha value of the Nan pixels is changed, and the underlying black appears as gray border around the color pixels.

I tried several ways. The easiest one, which actually worked for me was to use the `tikz` terminal with option `externalimages` which saves images created `with image` as separate png file.
These png file also contains transparency, and the final result has the same artifacts.
But you can use imagemagick's `convert` to change the transparent NaN pixels of the png to white with

```
convert temp.001.png -alpha off -fill white -opaque black temp.001.png
```

So, a fully working plot file is

```
# plot.plt
set size ratio -1

set palette defined ( 0 '#D73027', 1 '#F46D43', 2 '#FDAE61', 3 '#FEE090', 4 '#FFFFD9', 5 '#E0F3F8', 6 '#ABD9E9', 7 '#74ADD1', 8 '#4575B4' )

set ytics 100
set yrange reverse

set term tikz standalone externalimages background "white"; set output "temp.tex"

plot "data.txt" u 1:2:3 matrix with image notitle

# temp.001.png is the external image which contains only the 'with image' part
# We must remove the #00000000 color, which represents the NaN pixels
# I couldn't replace the colors directly, but I could first remove the alpha channel
# and then change black to white, because no other black pixel appear
!convert temp.001.png -alpha off -fill white -opaque black temp.001.png

set output #Closes the temporary output file.   
!sed -e 's|/Title|%/Title|' -e 's|/Subject|%/Subject|' -e 's|/Creator|%/Creator|' -e 's|/Author|%/Author|' < temp.tex > graph.tex
!pdflatex graph.tex
```

Mupdf screen shot for graph.pdf:

[image]

Note, that I used `standalone` to be able to directly compile the resulting file, so that I could check the result.

A more cumbersome alternative would be to "manually" plot `with image` to a png file, and include that in a second plot, like I described in [Big data surface plots: Call gnuplot from tikz to generate bitmap and include automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131106/33933) Then you can have more influence on how the png is generated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this Christoph, and also for explaining the origin of this issue! I just have some more questions regarding differences that appear when using this method:
1) additional labels seem to be ignored by this method: things such as `set label "\\textbf{\\small{\\textsf{".YYYYMM."}}}" at graph(.8), graph(.04)`;
2) all the fonts are slightly smaller than on other plots using cairolatex, do you know how that could be fixed?

Comment: I guess the labels don't appear, because they are hidden behind the now opaque image. Use `front` to set the label in front of the image: `set label ... front`. To increase the font size, use the `font` terminal option: `set terminal tikz ... font ",12"`.

Comment: Great, once again: thank you very much for looking into this! Other small differences will be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, `with image pixels` seems to do the "trick" and will create a file without grey surrounding of `NaN` datapoints. Tested with gnuplot 5.2.6.

```
 plot FILE u 1:2:3 matrix with image pixels notitle
```

**Code:**

```
### avoid shading around NaN datapoints
reset session

set size ratio -1
FILE = "data.txt"

set palette defined ( 0 '#D73027', 1 '#F46D43', 2 '#FDAE61', 3 '#FEE090', 4 '#FFFFD9', 5 '#E0F3F8', 6 '#ABD9E9', 7 '#74ADD1', 8 '#4575B4' )

set term cairolatex dashed color
set output "temp.tex"

plot FILE u 1:2:3 matrix with image pixels notitle

set output
### end of code
```

**Result:** (a PNG of a screenshot, since it looks like I cannot add a PDF here)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant alternative solution. It would be even better than the accepted answer if only the files produced with this method were not so huge (sadly making them impractical).

Comment: @Alex thank you for your feedback. Well, I didn't pay special attention to the PDF size with the test data. I would be interested in learning what makes it so huge and how to eventually reduce the size. In case you find out, please let me know.